# RESTful API design - how to ensure particular behaviour from HTTP methods?

Tags: rest, get

While developing RESTful API how do we ensure something like this - GET does not do any create or update?

Do we have any way by which we can ensure and stop get from doing any update / create?

Answer (score 0):

There is no programmatic or automatic way to do that if that is what you are asking. As a server-side developer you have to design your `GET` calls that way.

Technically it is not even true that there is no update/create. `GET` may write logs, audit records, cache entries, etc. The point is, it should be "[safe](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)", it should have no side-effects which the caller would normally not consider.